# Anyone can tale me why my Original list updating when I Update in copied list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, indexing

This code give me --> `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`‍♂️ that means the code still updating the original list e.i: `matrix2`

```py
matrix2 = [[0, 1, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 1, 5]]

def changedItto_zero(col, row, column, arr):
    matrix_copy = arr[:] # --> copy list using slice , but it still updating ‍♂️ the original list
    matrixLen_row = len(arr)
    matrixLen_col = len(arr[0])
    for row_index in range(0, matrixLen_row):
        for column_index in range(0, matrixLen_col):
            matrix_copy[row][column_index] = 0
            matrix_copy[row_index][column] = 0
    return matrix_copy



def change(arr):
    global col
    matrixLen_row = len(arr)
    matrixLen_col = len(arr[0])
    for row_index in range(0, matrixLen_row):
        for column_index in range(0, matrixLen_col):
            if(arr[row_index][column_index] == 0):
                find_row, find_column = row_index, column_index
                print('row ', find_row, ' col ', find_column)
               #  print('matx ', arr)
                col += 1
                finded = changedItto_zero(col, find_row, find_column, arr)
    return finded


print(change(matrix2))

# Right Output:[[0,0,0,0],[0,4,5,0],[0,3,1,0]]
```

Comment: You made a shallow copy, you need a deep copy.

Comment: `arr[:]` creates a shallow copy, the list itself is new but the objects inside of it are the same. In this case, you can just do `matrix_copy = [row[:] for row in arr]`

Comment: If you want to create a *copy* use `.copy`. This behavior is pretty standard for most programming languages.

Comment: You might consider moving to `numpy` if you're going to be doing matrix work.

Comment: @Kat -- Did you not see that he IS using `.copy()`?

Comment: @Kat they *are creating a copy*, using `arr[:]` which is exactly equivalent to `arr.copy()`

Comment: `.copy` from `import copy` is shallow; however `.copy` from `numpy` is a deep copy. That being said, either use `import copy` then make this change `matrix_copy = copy.deepcopy(arr)` or use `numpy.copy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like someone commented, the problem is that `arr[:]` creates a copy of the `arr` list but not a copy of its contents. You can confirm this by printing `id(matrix_copy)` and `id(arr)` right after creating the copy, which should display different values, meaning different lists. But if you do the same with the first element of each list (`id(matrix_copy[0])` and `id(arr[0])`) you'll see that they are the same list. A simple solution to this problem is creating a deep copy explicitly:

```
matrix_copy = copy.deepcopy(arr)  # You should import copy to use this function
```